# Output values from multiple counters in Powershell

Tags: sql-server, powershell, performancecounter

I have the following bit of code that I have borrowed, but I am not getting the output I expected. Eventually I want to create a list/array for each counter containing the last x number of values. 
But I expected that the `$obj` would be a list of counters that I could step though and the code below would give an output that would have `***` between each counter collected, but this is not the case?

How can I loop though each counter in turn and get its value?

```
$counters = get-counter -ComputerName sql -Counter "\SQLServer:General Statistics\User Connections","\SQLServer:Memory Manager\Memory Grants Pending","\SQLServer:SQL Statistics\batch requests/sec","\SQLServer:SQL Statistics\sql compilations/sec","\SQLServer:SQL Statistics\sql re-compilations/sec" -SampleInterval 1

foreach($metric in $counters)            
{            
  $obj = $metric.CounterSamples | Select-Object -Property Path, CookedValue;            

  write-host $obj 
  write-host "***"
}
```

The current output I get is below:

```
@{Path=\\sql\\sqlserver:general statistics\user connections; CookedValue=96} @{Path=\\sql\\sqlserver:memory manager\memory grants pending; CookedValue=0} @{Path=\\sql\\sqlserver:sql statistics\batch requests/sec; CookedValue=110.969626692457} @{Path=\\sql\\sqlserver:sql statistics\sql compilations/sec; CookedValue=17.9950745987768} @{Path=\\sql\\sqlserver:sql statistics\sql re-compilations/sec; CookedValue=5.99835819959228}
***
```

I was hoping for more like this:

```
Counters 1 = 0.5
***
Counter 2 = 1.2
***
```

This would break the output into the separate counters, but I think I understand the comments now.

Comment: Be specific when asking questions (eg $obj is a list of CounterSamples for one iteration of $counters, presumably $counters is your list of counters). You also don't explain what output you DO get. This looks like it should output a bunch of statistics to the console (but not in any list you can do anything with).

Comment: you might wanna have a look at the help for get-counter, start-job, get-gob etc

Comment: Thank you Deadly-Bagel, i was not looking at this right, I needed to be looping though the items in $obj not $Counters. Thank you and if you want to post it as an answer I happly accept.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you looking for?

```
$counters = $(Get-Counter -Counter '\Processor(_Total)\% Processor Time', '\LogicalDisk(_Total)\% Free Space').CounterSamples | Select-Object -Property Path, CookedValue

foreach($obj in $counters)            
{            
  Write-Host -Object '***'
  $obj = $($obj | ConvertTo-Json|
      ForEach-Object -Process {
        [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_)
      }) -replace ‘[{},\n]’
  Write-Host -Object $obj
  Write-Host -Object '***'
}
```

Comment: As above this issue was how I was looking at the returned variable and Deadly_Bagel had the answer. Cheers